# Get text of parent's parent?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have the following code in jQuery Mobile :

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" id="#listview" data-divider-theme="d">
    <li data-role="list-divider" class="name">Mr. Sam</li>
            <li data-icon="false" class="details">
                       <a onclick="getInfo()">
```

And on my `onclick`, I want to access the `Mr. Sam`. Here's the following code I'm trying in the JS:

`var info = $(this).parent().parent().text();`

Because, I'm clicking on `<a>`, it's parent is `<li>`, and it's parent is `<li>` containing Mr. Sam. But I'm doing something wrong, as `alert(info);` alerts a blank output.
What do I need to change? I've even tried, `.html()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your markup the target `li` is not grand-parent of the clicked element, it's previous sibling of the parent element:

```
<li data-role="list-divider" class="name">Mr. Sam</li>
                                               ---^
```

You can use `prev` method:

```
var info = $(this).parent().prev().text();
```

Also note that in your code `this` refers to window object, you can pass `this` to your function:

```
<a onclick="getInfo(this)">
```

```
function getInfo(elem) {
   var info = $(elem).parent().prev().text(); 
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F8wt8/

Since you are using jQuery (after removing `#` from `ul`s ID attribute) instead of `onclick` attribute you can use `click` method.

```
$('#listview li.details a').click(function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var info = $(this).parent().prev().text();
   // console.log(info);
})
```